# How to sync Firebird with SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database, synchronization, firebird

I have a desktop app which uses a Firebird database. And it works fine, yet I want to also have access to that data online.

So I thought it might be possible to sync the data between Firebird and SQL Server. I know there is a tool called `dbconvert` but its quite expensive.

Any other solutions which come to your mind? Thanks!

Comment: Firebird database can be accessed just like the MS SQL and online anywhere (if you are right and it is programmed). 
Write in detail what you need to do.

Comment: Wjy do you need to synchronize? Just create an OData / Web API frontend on that database and expose that data online ....

Comment: You maybe misunderstood me. The database is stored locally. PC is running in specific hours e.g. 8.00-20.00. So at midnight i will not be able to access it via web. Database includes specific data like: number of customers daily, number of visits, income (and its breakdown etc). I want to access this data all day long (so when pc is switched off, database should keep data from e.g. 19:59. In fact there are no cost-wise firebird hostings..

Comment: There is not a readymade solution for this. You will need to find some sync tool and configure it, or write a sync solution yourself. Both are out of scope for stackoverflow, as either a "tool suggestion request", or "too broad".

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change the database. If you want to access your desktop app online you can, for example, place your desktop APP + firebird database on windows server and create a access through RemoteApp. Then you can accessed your application from anywhere (if the client OS can RemoteApp and online)

**update**

You can place application and database on a different type of server if you will reach them through some "remote desktop".

Comment: sure thing, but as far as I understood Julia - she wanted to avoid some costs. Windows server is an additional cost for her. But I might be wrong ;)

Comment: If she want to transfer data to SQL server database, so I guess that some Server where is SQL Server running is available.

Comment: @Majkl - thanks. Yet this solution makes it a bit complicated - in fact it will reflect total app on the server. I want to display only specific database columns, not all of them. Thats why im looking for something like web dashboard.

Comment: We probably do not understand. Do you have a computer in company that runs 24 hours a day and you have to access it from the Internet (via remote desktop)? If yes, just move desktop app + database into server. Than via remote desktop you join a server and application use there. btw, if you wanted to move your data into MS SQL Server where it is running (computer)? How would you received data from the database?

Comment: just like mentioned on the top - pc is working 8am - 8pm.